# Using class variable in @compnent animation Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an animation that is expanding the height on hover. I am taking the height of the label in ngOnInit because that label is auto height and doesn't animate properly with just :hover this is my ts @Component with the animation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('buttonState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        height: '100%'
       })),
      state('active', style({
        height: this.buttonHeight
       })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('1.5s ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1.5s ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

The problem is that the this.buttonHeight gives me Cannot read property 'buttonHeight' of undefined. I guess that 'this' is not the class in the @Compnent or is not defined yet. How can I make it work?

This is how i take the height:

```
  @ViewChild('button') button : ElementRef;
  buttonHeight : number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonHeight = this.button.nativeElement.offsetHeight
  }
```

In html:

```
<label [@buttonState]="state" (mouseover)="toggleState()" (mouseout)="toggleState()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to get the animation to work but you can't use this.buttonHeight in animation.
You have to add a parameter:

HTML

```
<label [@buttonState]="{value: state, params: {buttonHeight: buttonHeight}}" (mouseover)="toggleState()"
    (mouseout)="toggleState()">LABEL</label>
```

TS

```
animations: [
    trigger('buttonState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        height: '100%'
      })),
      state('active', style({
        height: "{{buttonHeight}}px"
      }), { params: { buttonHeight: "4" } }),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('1.5s ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1.5s ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

You have to add a default value for each param you define (else you get an error).

I hope I could lead you in the right direction (:

Comment: Good catch. I was thinking about binding the component instance and haven't realized that is possible to pass parameters from the template.

Comment: I found this too I am still not able to do it. because I have another problem where i need to trigger the [@buttonState] animation from different node element with mouseover and mouseout no on the same div. I will open another question if you have any ideas

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how `this` can be bind to the component instance, because it is used in an array instead of a function that could be bind somehow. I haven't found this possibility on documentation either.
I think what you want to accomplish can be done with CSS.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class Create implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('button') button : ElementRef;
  buttonHeight : number;
  isActive = false;

  animate() {
   isActive = !isActive;
   if (isActive) {
     this.buttonState.nativeElment.height = `${this.buttonHeight}px`;
   } else {
     this.buttonState.nativeElment.height = '100%';
   }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonHeight = this.button.nativeElement.offsetHeight
  }
```

```css
.active {
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}

.inactive {
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<label [ngClass]="{active: isActive, inactive: !isActive}" (mouseover)="animate()" (mouseout)="animate()">
```

Comment: yes thank you. I found the other way with interpolation and params, but I have another problem there, because I need to trigger the animation from different node. If I can't do it maybe I will use this way/ if you have any idea: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331101/triggering-animation-from-different-html-node-with-mouseover-and-mouseout-angula

Comment: I see you removed the question. Anyway, it would be possible using a service to implement an observer pattern. One component will subscribe to the service for changes and the other component will delegate into the service method that fire the change.